# How to create a data.frame from expression?

Tags: r, rlang

I want to create a data frame from an expression saved into an object.

Whereas this works:

```r
library(dplyr)

regular_chr_vec <- c(a = "lion", b = "zebra")
bind_rows(regular_chr_vec)

##   a     b    
##   <chr> <chr>
## 1 lion  zebra
```

This doesn't:

```r
library(rlang)

as_expression_vec <- parse_expr("c(a = \"lion\", b = \"zebra\")")
bind_rows(!!!as_expression_vec)
```

> Error: Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector.

Nor this:

```r
as_expression_vec <- parse_expr("c(a = \"lion\", b = \"zebra\")")
bind_rows(!!as_expression_vec)
```

> Error: Can't use `!!` in a non-quoting function

---

So my question is: How can I create a dataframe if I'm just handed with `as_expression_vec`?

```r
##   a     b    
##   <chr> <chr>
## 1 lion  zebra
```

I intentionally kept the question minimal and with no context to not distract the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution

```
library(rland)
library(dplyr)

as_expression_vec <- parse_expr("c(a = \"lion\", b = \"zebra\")")

bind_rows(eval(as_expression_vec))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  a     b    
  <chr> <chr>
1 lion  zebra
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I knew it was a simple thing